# How to convert images with following extensions jpg, pdf, gif, xls, xlsx, doc, docx, rtf, bmp, jpeg, csv to .TIFF in java?

Tags: java, image-conversion

How to convert images with following extensions 
`jpg, pdf, gif, xls, xlsx, doc, docx, rtf, bmp, jpeg, csv` to `.TIFF` in Java ?

I want to convert all the above mentioned image extensions to .TIFF extension.

Comment: Have you tried researching on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Commons Sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/imaging/) has support for reading and writing `BMP`, `JPEG/JFIF`, `TIFF`, `GIF` and `PNG` from your list.

[Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) can convert `PDF` files to images (see [PDFToImage](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/PDFToImage.html) code).

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) can read `doc`, `docx`, `xls` and `xlsx`, but I am not aware of an easy way to convert them to an image (if that is what you would want to do). What you could probably do is make a conversion to a `PDF` first and then from `PDF` to an image.